# debezium - are there any solutions to resolve "The db history topic is missing" errors

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

A debezium connector was created separately for each table in the database. Connectors that connect to the same database share the same database.history.kafka.topic and database.server.name. Also connectors use schema_only for snapshot.mode.

A db history topic is missing error occurred. So I dropped the history topic and ran it again, "the db history topic is missing" error still occurred. If I changed snapshot.mode from schema_only to schema_only_recovery, "schema isn't known to this connector" error occurred after starting the second connector connecting to the same database.

How can I resolve "db history topic is missing" error.
And Should the db history topic not be shared by connectors?

Comment: Did you had any success with it? If yes would you mind sharing some steps? If not, this is something that may help if you havent read it https://groups.google.com/g/debezium/c/p_jSnW5B3oU

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue when I was trying to delete all the Debezium topics in Kafka and start from scratch. I suspected that some state was being saved somewhere that was causing the issue. After looking I found that Debezium had created a temp file at `/tmp/connect.offsets` when I created the connector.

By deleting this file I was able to start from scratch after deleting the topics and use the same connector name. The `connect.offsets` file looks like it stored a mapping of the connector name to binlog offsets, but I wanted Debzium to create a new snapshot anyways instead of trying to do a schema recovery.